# Why does my programme not react to "Alt" + "F4"?

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a GUI for a little java game. I have a class `Window` that extends a `JFrame` and contains an object of `MainMenuPanel`, a class that extends a `JPanel` and contains some `JButtons`.

I want that the `MainMenuPanel` is replaced with an object of `OptionsPanel`, a class that also extends a `JPanel`, after clicking the `optionsButton`.

I realized this using the following code:

```
public class MainMenuPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private Window window;  
    private JButton playButton;
    private JButton optionsButton;
    private ImageIcon buttonIcon;
    private SavegamesPanel savegamesPanel;
    private OptionsPanel optionsPanel;

    public MainMenuPanel(Window w)
    {
        window = w;

        setSize(window.getContentPane().getSize());
        setLocation(0, 0);
        setLayout(null);

        playButton = new JButton();
        optionsButton = new JButton();

        buttonIcon = new ImageIcon("res/buttonIcon.png");

        playButton.setIcon(buttonIcon);     
        playButton.setSize(200, 50);
        playButton.setLocation(((window.getContentPane().getWidth() - 200) / 2), ((window.getContentPane().getHeight() - 200) / 2));
        playButton.addActionListener(this);

        optionsButton.setIcon(buttonIcon);
        optionsButton.setSize(200, 50);
        optionsButton.setLocation(((window.getContentPane().getWidth() - 200) / 2), (((window.getContentPane().getHeight() - 200) / 2) + 50));
        optionsButton.addActionListener(this);

        add(playButton);
        add(optionsButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        if(e.getSource().equals(playButton))
        {
            //do things
        }
        else if(e.getSource().equals(optionsButton))
        {
            window.remove(this);

            optionsPanel = new OptionsPanel(window, null, 0);

            window.add(optionsPanel);
            window.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that after the panels have changed the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> does not work anymore and I do not understand why.

You might say that this is not very important but it will cause other problems for me later.

So I would be very happy if you could help me!

Comment: Alt + F4, at least in Windows, is normally used to close the current active window.

Comment: That is right. My problem is that it does not close the current active window after the panels changed.

Comment: Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Then don't use setSize() or setLocation(), the layout manager will determine the size and location. If you want to replace panels on a frame then use a [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) on the main panel. The main panel will then contain your 2 child panels and you control which one is visible at any given time.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Would you mind creating a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (ie, a simple main reproducing the problem) ? It will be easier to help you :)

Comment: @so.koni: you could try using `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(c);` or `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(c);` to get the top level window for your applet.

Comment: @camickr: Maybe I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, Alt+F4 simply tells the active window to close. The window needs to actually respond to this event for anything to actually happen.

You can either make use of `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` (e.g. somewhere in your JFrame construction chain), or you can explicitly listen for window events using a `java.awt.event.WindowListener` yourself. The WindowListener is called when the window is closed (either by the button or Alt-F4), and you will need to actively close the window (e.g. using `setVisible(false)`).

Unless you do something (very) weird, your panels inside the window should have no effect at all on the behaviour of the window with respect to closing.